# Nodejs function gets called multiple times

Tags: node.js

I am working on a parser in nodejs. Therefore I request a website and parse the HTML.
I am working with require("htmlparser") and require('follow-redirects').http for the requests.

```
requestSite(options);
console.log("Done\n");
parser.done();

function requestSite(options) {
http.get(options, function(res) {
    console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            parser.parseChunk(chunk.toString('utf8'));
    });
}).on('error', function(e) {
    console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
}
```

My problem now is that the done() is called before the requestSite function actually has finished its chunks resulting in following error:

> Writing to the handler after done() called is not allowed without
>   calling a reset()

How can I wait for the chunks to finish?

Comment: is there an on('end') event you can call it in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not taking account the asynchronous nature of nodejs. It will call `requestSite` and then moveon to execute the next statement and call `parser.done` before `requestSite` is done executing. Do this instead.

```
requestSite(options, parser);
console.log("Done\n");

function requestSite(options, parser) {
http.get(options, function(res) {
    console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            parser.parseChunk(chunk.toString('utf8'));
    })
    .on("end", function(){
          parser.done();
      })
}).on('error', function(e) {
    console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well this is the basic of node.js and the event driven architecture.

Node is not a line by line programing like php, python etc...

look at this simple example:

```
console.log(1);
setTimeout (function(err, res) {
    console.log(2);
}, 0);
console.log(3);
```

as you will think it should print: 1,2,3

but this will print 1,3,2.

In your example you should move the

```
 parser.done();
```

to the "end" of the http request.
currently you have an event for getting chunks of data, so simply use:
onEnd or something similar and than place the "parser.done()"